# Java Security Keys to String and Vice Versa

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

in reference to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079814/elliptic-curve-private-key-encoding-outputs), I would like to know why my code fails for a particular input and works for another.

Code:

```
import de.flexiprovider.core.FlexiCoreProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.FlexiECProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveParams;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveRegistry.BrainpoolP512r1;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter;


public class TestClass {

    public TestClass() {
        Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
        Security.addProvider(new FlexiECProvider());
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    public KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES");
        CurveParams ecParams = new BrainpoolP512r1();
        kpg.initialize(ecParams, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        return keyPair;
    }

    private String keyToPEMString(Object key) throws Exception {
        StringWriter signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        JcaPEMWriter pemWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter);
        pemWriter.writeObject(key);
        pemWriter.close();
        return signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter.toString();
    }

    public String[] generateB64EncodedKeyPair() throws Exception {
        String[] publicPrivateKeyPair = new String[2];
        KeyPair keyPair = generateKeyPair();
        publicPrivateKeyPair[0] = keyToPEMString(keyPair.getPublic());
        publicPrivateKeyPair[1] = keyToPEMString(keyPair.getPrivate());
        return publicPrivateKeyPair;
    }

    public String keyToString(Key anyKey) throws Exception {
        return keyToPEMString(anyKey);
    }

    public Key stringToKey(String encodedKey, boolean isPrivate) throws Exception {
        Key key = null;
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECIES");       //THIS POINT REFERRED
        BASE64Decoder b64 = new BASE64Decoder();
        //System.out.println("Stripped::");
        byte[] keyBytes = null;
        if (isPrivate) {
            encodedKey = encodedKey.replace("-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n", "").replace("-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            //System.out.println(encodedKey);
            keyBytes = b64.decodeBuffer(encodedKey);
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
            key = (PrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

//            PEMParser pemRd = new PEMParser(new StringReader(encodedKey));
//            ASN1ObjectIdentifier ecOID = (ASN1ObjectIdentifier) pemRd.readObject();
//            X9ECParameters ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getByOID(ecOID);
//            if (ecSpec == null) {
//                System.out.println("ecSpec not found for named curve");
//                System.exit(0);
//            }
//            System.out.println(pemRd.readObject());
//            PEMKeyPair pemPair = (PEMKeyPair) pemRd.readObject();
//
//            KeyPair pair = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC").getKeyPair(pemPair);
//            key = pair.getPrivate();

        } else {
            encodedKey = encodedKey.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
            //System.out.println(encodedKey);
            keyBytes = b64.decodeBuffer(encodedKey);
            X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
            key = (PublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        }
        return key;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass obj = new TestClass();
        try {

            KeyPair keyPair = obj.generateKeyPair();

            System.out.println("*******************************************");

            System.out.println(obj.keyToPEMString(keyPair.getPublic()));
            System.out.println(obj.keyToPEMString(keyPair.getPrivate()));

            System.out.println("*******************************************");

            System.out.println(obj.stringToKey(obj.keyToPEMString(keyPair.getPublic()), false));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(obj.stringToKey(obj.keyToPEMString(keyPair.getPrivate()), true));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The method **StringToKey** has been successfully used by me for converting RSA keys from their PEM format. On using it for EC keys, Public keys get converted without any hassle but Private Keys do not.

I have commented on a part in the private key conversion section, it has just been put to mention that I have tried that snippet as well, but with out a satisfactory result.

I need to generate two keys and store them onto the users machine so that they can be loaded as per need.

the other option i have is to store them in a .p12 file and load them via KeyStore, which i have successfully done, but I am interested to know if PEM converted Elliptical Private Keys strings can also be loaded considering the output or encoded conversion below.

Here is the output of the code above:

```
*******************************************
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGbMBQGByqGSM49AgEGCSskAwMCCAEBDQOBggAERHQce1+hQ4jXBiB7VTKJ1UFR
xqtpqCb5Hh4MiElJNiovj8TFCfONRcYywBlqopCK45JctuMWAelTG0y+sjHB1E7H
2U3wzSMbU5q6qqeK2WoaN1uoeIYV3zBVtOdKtdqUy1fhubWfQUdQDumOCds6dFXD
5N+RHZkt6/hnXtPdWe4=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MEYCAQEEQQCXr25i9d8VeMSRBG5GJ3s+Sxj3UQhyTr9MBoPPhYTlo8dF/+gXUgrE
tW2mDD4MmtofIqWvXoVObW/FjW0NfY/a
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

*******************************************
W =
(44741c7b5fa14388d706207b553289d54151c6ab69a826f91e1e0c884949362a2f8fc4c509f38d45c632c0196aa2908ae3925cb6e31601e9531b4cbeb231c1d4,
 4ec7d94df0cd231b539abaaaa78ad96a1a375ba8788615df3055b4e74ab5da94cb57e1b9b59f4147500ee98e09db3a7455c3e4df911d992debf8675ed3dd59ee)
de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveRegistry$BrainpoolP512r1@e9ef02e5

de.flexiprovider.api.exceptions.InvalidKeySpecException: codec.asn1.ASN1Exception: ASN.1 type mismatch!
Expected: codec.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier
In      : codec.pkcs8.PrivateKeyInfo
At index: 1
Got tag : 4 and class: 0
        at de.flexiprovider.ec.keys.ECKeyFactory.generatePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:125)
        at de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(KeyFactory.java:61)
        at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:342)
        at TestClass.stringToKey(TestClass.java:70)
        at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:110)
```

Alternatively, I have a doubt regarding the inline comment in KeyFactory line of the StringToKey method. I have tried selecting a different instances, like:
"EC"

"EC","BC"

"EC","FlexiEC"

"ECDSA"

"ECDSA","BC"

"ECDSA","FlexiEC"

Sadly, **None** have worked.

How can i successfully convert the PEM of my EC Private Key to a Private key again?
OR
How can i create a PEM of the EC private key that would be easily reconvertible to its original form?